# Multiple threads on dual core cpu

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

I'm studying about threads and slightly confused about 1 thing.

If I have a single process with multiple threads running on a dual/quad core CPU, will different threads run concurrently on different cores?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It Depends.

At least on Linux, each task gets assigned to a set of CPUs that it can execute on (`processor affinity`). And, at least on Linux, the scheduler will try to schedule the task on the same processor as last time, so that it gets the best benefit of CPU cache re-use. The hilarious thing is that it doesn't always rebalance when the system is under load, so it is possible to run one core quite hot and contested and leave three cores cool and relatively idle. (I've seen this exact behavior with the Folding @ Home client.)

You can *force* the affinity you need with the `pthread_setaffinity_np(3)` routine for threaded applications or `sched_setaffinity(2)` for more traditional Unix-style `fork(2)`ed applications. Or you can use the `taskset(1)` program to set the affinity before or after starting an application. (Which is the approach I took with my silly Folding @ Home client -- it was easy to modify the initscript to call `taskset(1)` to set the affinity of each client process correctly, so each client got its own core and didn't compete for resources with the other clients on different sibling HyperThreaded 'faked' execution cores.)

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes

---

It depends on the language, the library, and the operating system, and whether the threaded application ever actually has multiple runnable threads at the same point in time, but usually the answer is *"yes".*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

Although I just found this in my book.

"The major difference can be seen when using multiprocessor systems, user threads completely managed by the threading library can't be ran in parallel on the different CPUs, although this means they will run fine on uniprocessor systems. Since kernel threads use the kernel scheduler, different kernel threads can run on different CPUs."

So i am  a little confused!!

Answer (score 1):

You can never be sure of that fact, but if it is processor-intensive (such as a game) then most likely yes.

Comment: Why will threads from a single process run in parallel on a multi-core cpu IF they are from a game?

Thread t = new Thread(game_threads=true);

This way the scheduler will know that this thread can run in parallel with other threads?

Comment: @gfelisberto: See the parentheses? A game would be an *example* of something processor-intensive that would cause different threads to run on different cores, since they can't really run on the same core what with the processor's time being taken up. I think. It was over two years ago. Anyway, if the threads aren't active at the same time, and the other cores are taken up by something processor-intensive, it stands to reason that they might run on the same core. IANACD, though. (I Am Not A Chip Designer). And, of course, "you can never be sure of that fact" was the important part.

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to synchronized your every core of processor with memory by using volatile keyword which ensure that every core of processor getting new updated value from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Somnetimes the threads will run concurrently, sometimes not.  Its all up to the package you use and the operating system and how CPU intensive each thread each.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you are loosing the idea behind concurrency; it's not that you are looking to run processes on multiple cores.  Instead, you're needing to not block on one process the entire time.  A perfect example of this is with threading network listeners.  You want to perform an accept which will actually create a new client->server socket.  After this you want to do some processing with that socket while still be able to take new connections.  This is where you would want to generate a thread to perform the processing so that the accept can get back on track to waiting for a new connection.

Comment: Ok i am giving a very abstract example here, this is from my lecturer. Say if we have MS Word running and suppose 1 thread deals with spell checking and another deals with grammar checking, both threads being from msword.exe, can the spell check thread run on one core and grammar check run on another core at the same time.

Comment: this rationale for concurrency was valid when we were all using single-core processors that were incapable of true parallelism.  Nowadays, multi-core processors are everywhere, and if an application wants to improve its speed, it needs to actually distribute its work across multiple cores.  Threads don't exist just to work around non-blocking I/O anymore.